# Eclipse CDT gives false member 'x' not initialized

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse Kepler and CDT 8.3.0, along with the Android NDK plugin and SDL. I have a problem that was supposed to be fixed a while back. I have a Camera class which looks like this:

Camera.h

```
class Camera {

public:
    Camera();
    ~Camera();
private:

}
```

Camera.cpp:

```
Camera::Camera() {

}

Camera::~Camera();
```

Eclipse gives me a warning: Member m_width is not initialized in this constructor. I have not yet done anything with the Camera class, what you see here is all there is - there is no m_width variable.

Another problem I have is that Eclipse seems to be able to find all SDL types, like SDL_Window and SDL_Surface, but not the functions like SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO). Is there a bug in Codan? Or have I linked something incorrectly?